# Show that a set is reducible to another set

Tags: computability, reductions

Consider an operator $+$ defined on $P(\mathbb{N})$ as follows

$$A + B = \{2x:\ x\in A\}\cup\{2x + 1:\ x\in B\}$$
Show that $A$ is $m$-reducible to $A+B$ and $B$ is $m$-reducible to $A+B$

As per the definition of reducibility $B$ is reducible to $A$ if there exists a total computable function $f$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{N}$
$$x\in B \iff f(x) \in A$$

**My Thoughts:**

So, here given any two sets $A$ and $B$ I have to show that $A$ is reducible to $A+B$. That means that I have to come up with a function $f$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{N}$
$$x\in A \iff f(x)\in A+B$$
If I take the function $f(x) = 2x$, then if $x$ is in $A$ then $f(x)$ is in $A+B$. And if $f(x)$ is in $A+B$ then $f(x)$ must be  $= 2y$ for $y\in A$.

This looks like a correct argument to me, but I am not sure if there are any flaws in it.

Comment: You have a complete argument in the answer. I'm not sure what you're asking. We're not here to grade your homework.

Comment: I was not sure if the approach is correct. As I am doing it first time

Comment: You should trust yourself more. The goal in mathematics is to reach a situation where you are able to recognize a correct mathematical argument.

Comment: Haha yes sure thanks for the advice